# parsing a float from web-service with JSON

Tags: web-services, json, ios

to parse a NSString i have used this :

```
NSString *adress=[stations objectForKey:@"adress_station"];
```

what about a float, how should i call it, i try to do that :

```
       float distance=[stations objectForKey:@"distance"];
```

but i have got an error :

```
incompatible type in initialization
```

i don't want to put it in NSString, i need it as float because i need it in other operations :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float distance = [[stations objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];
```

objectForKey returns an object (in this case I assume an NSString).

Calling `-floatValue` on an NSString will get the data as a float.

Comment: thx a lot, it works like a charm, but when i receive it from web-service, it's rounded with one number (i.e: 7.1) but when i display it on iPhone it's not rounded any more (7.057124) :))

Comment: That would depend on what you're doing with the value after you've parsed it. Care to elaborate?

Comment: the value received is for example 7.057124, i want it to be 7.1 :)

Comment: @Malek Do you actually want it representing as 7.1 or just being displayed as 7.1?

Printing it using a formatter of %0.1f would give you the required 7.1 for display purposes.

NSLog(@"%0.1f", distance);

Otherwise to actually round the float you can use something like: distance = roundf(10 * distance) / 10;

Comment: no actually i want to use it later for more calculations, not only for displaying :)

Comment: your function didn't work distance = roundf(10 * distance) / 10;

Comment: If you're not using C99 (or better) you can try the following:

distance = distance*10.0f;
distance = (distance > (floor(distance)+0.5f)) ? ceil(distance) : floor(distance);
distance = distance/10.0f;